# Does "Until when" sound natural for native speakers?

Tags: word-usage, word-request

In some languages such as my native languages (Kurdish and Persian), when we want to ask about the exact limit point of time for something, we use two words which are exactly equal to this two words in English: Until When?

For example, we say:
**Until when do I have time to finish this project?**

I would like to know how much this way of asking is natural in different English speaking countries? Or if it sounds pretty weird to you, please tell me how you say the above sentence in English.

Answer (score 27):

I think the “until when” construct can work fine in a question like this, although I think I’d be inclined to change the order of the words:

> I have until when to finish this project?

Also, it’s worth noting that we will often put additional emphasis on the word *when* in such questions, particularly when expressing surprise. For example:

> Ted: I’ll need this project done by Friday.
>   Ned: I have until ***when*** to finish this project?

In this dialogue, Ned isn’t really asking Ted for a deadline; he is expressing incredulity that the deadline is coming so soon. In other words, Ned knows the project needs to be done by Friday, but he is astonished that he has so little time to accomplish so much work.

Of course, there are many other ways people can ask about an upcoming deadline. I especially like the suggestions provided by [Bob Jarvis](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/200057) and [Ronnie Childs](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/199974/does-until-when-sound-natural-for-native-speakers#comment388829_199974) elsewhere in answers and comments under this question:

> - *When is the deadline for this project?*
> - *How long do I have to finish this project?*

Comment: Another way of asking the question would be "How long do I have to finish the project?" and I would expect a time period, like "2 weeks". If I ask "I have until when..." I would expect a date or day, like "March 26th"

Comment: I think "When is this due?" is being overlooked as a concise alternative.

Comment: Hi, by the way, is it the right sentence in a questioner's posting? `For example, we say: Until when do I have time to finish this project?`. I cannot understand why the word of 'time' is placed between 'I have' and 'to finish~'.

Comment: @Tae-Bbong-E - That sounds too wordy to me. I might ask, "How much time do I have to finish this project?" or "When do I need to finish this project?" but I would not combine those two to construct a sentence like the one you provided.

Comment: Hi @J.R. Yes, what you said is what I wanted to point out. Plus, technically speaking, the sentence I provided is originally from this post of Yazdan Samiei Poor. :-) By the way thanks for your kindly teaching me!

Answer (score 17):

There are certainly sentences where it would sound entirely appropriate.

> Boss: Keep working on this.
>   Employee: Until when?
>
> Parent: You are grounded!
>   Child: Until when?

Both usages are complete sentences.  Used as part of a sentence sounds a bit more strained and unnatural.

Comment: The words "until when" do not gramatically constitute a complete sentence, because a sentence must have a verb.  In casual conversation, however, such questions imply the previous statement to become complete: "Until when (am I grounded)"

Answer (score 12):

**Until when** is occasionally used but not nearly as often as just **when** or **by when**.

So most common are:

> When do I have to finish this project
>   and
>   By when do I have to finish this project.

But these two constructions don't necessarily mean the same thing.

The first is ambiguous; it can be understood either as **at what time/on what day** do I have to finish it - or **by when do I have to finish it**.

The second means **by when must it be completed** - by what time, day or other period.

People also ask:

> What is the deadline for completion

So my recommendation is that you stick to: **By when does it have to be completed**.

[Here is a related Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=until+when%2Cby+when&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3), comparing the use of *by when* and *until when*.

Comment: I would like just out of pure personal curiosity, would you completely "discard" to use the "Until when"? Even though it is grammatically correct?

Comment: Not at all. Depending on the context, I might well use it, as J.R. illustrates.

Answer (score 6):

`Until when` is not a particularly common construct in this situation. You would be more likely to hear `How long`, as in:

> How long do I have to finish this assignment?

Comment: This is the only answer that explicitly answers the 'does it sound natural' part of the question. The answer to that is (as this answer correctly states), in the context of the question: 'no, it does not sound natural'. It only sounds natural if you put a different spin on the original question.

Answer (score 5):

(Note: This is from a Northeastern U.S. native speaker's perspective.)

"Until when ..." is okay-ish, if a bit stilted. But "Until when do I have time ..." is just too clunky to be considered good colloquial English. See J.R.'s response for good ways to use "until when".

But this answer is to highlight what a previous comment pointed out: that the most natural way to say this would use the word "due":

> When is the/this/our project due?

This is exactly how my students would ask me, multiple times throughout the semester.

Answer (score 4):

Not a native, but I think natives would most commonly use

> How much time do I have to finish this project?

However, I believe

> Until when do I have to finish this project?

Might be grammatically sound. Now I am not entirely sure whether a native would use that or not

Comment: As a footnote, this native speaker would have no problem using that.

Comment: As a native without any restriction of using "until when", what would you instinctively say??

Comment: @eefar As a native British English speaker, I would never say "until when" unless I was deliberately using an *unusual* choice of words or grammar for some reason. "Until when do I have do finish" is confusing. "Until Thursday" (for example) means "the interval of time start now and ending on Thursday." You don't *finish* a project during an *interval* of time, you finish it at a *moment* in time. A better sentence would be just "When do I have to finish this project?" or "By when..." (or less formally, "When do I have to finish this project by?")not "Until when..."

Comment: @alephzero Fully agree. "Until when do I have to stand here?" makes perfect sense, as it's asking about a duration; "Until when do I have to finish this project" doesn't, because the response "You have to finish it until Thursday" doesn't make sense.

Comment: @DavidRicherby "You have until Thursday to finish it." makes perfect sense, and is the answer I'd expect if somebody asked "Until when do I have to finish this?" Unlike your "stand here" example, that doesn't mean you have to spend every moment between now and Thursday "finishing" it; it just means that at some point between now and Thursday, it has to be finished. The "Until when..." wording wouldn't be my first choice, but it doesn't seem particularly problematic to me.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist "You have until Thursday to finish it" and "You have to finish it until Thursday" are two completely different constructions. I suppose I could accept "Until when do I have to finish" if parsing "have" as "possess" (i.e., "What time period do I have, in which I can finish?") rather than as part of the phrasal verb "have to [do something]".

Answer (score 3):

> Until when do I have time to finish this project?

I think there are two problems here:

- We don't need the word 'time' if we are using a preposition that relates the concept of time.
- *Until* is a general word for something that is going to be happening, or true, for a certain time, and then stop being true (focusing on the period *before* the stop time). However, to focus on the deadline itself, we tend to use *by* (see [*Common Mistakes in Business English: The difference between “by” and “until”*](https://blog.harwardcommunications.com/2012/04/12/the-difference-between-by-and-until/)).

So we could say

> **By when do I have to finish this project?**

...and if we aren't squeamish about finishing a sentence with a preposition, a UK speaker speaking *informally* might be likely to say:

> **When do I have to finish this project by?**

To answer your title question though, "Until when" is perfectly natural for other cases:

> "I'm working in the library."
>   *"Until when?"*
>   " 'Til lunchtime. I have to hand in this project by this afternoon"